# Exporting values from SQL Server to Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I live in Brasil and decimal separators are commas. For a bunch of reasons, I use dots as decimal separators in SQL Server, which is different from Excel.

With that being said, I would like to know why the following query

```
select 1.0*5
```

is understood as text in Excel (if so), when copying and pasting, and dots are not converted to commas, while

```
select cast(1.0*5 as float)
```

is understood as float in Excel.

**What is the type of result in the first query?**

**UPDATE**

If the query were

```
select 1.1*5
```

the result of copy and paste in Excel cell would be `5.5`. It is not possible to convert this to value in Excel.

While the second query would result in `5,5`. I can use the use this value in Excel in an addition operation, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it directly IN Excel, it seems that your regional settings are not seeing that as an operation with a decimal, but rather text.  If you change your regional settings to US, it would probably resolve it correctly.

The difference between the two is that you are literally telling the value to be cast differently than the default.  So your regional setting is overridden.

Excel, as smart as it is, tends to make many assumptions that could be tied to any number of things.  Sometimes you just have to deal with it.

In the end, your 2nd query is likely to produce better results.